# Image standarization technique methods

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I want to know what are the types of image standardizations techniques available. For example, I'm working on hemoglobin concentration detection using photographs in which the patient pull lower conjunctiva downwards with one hand while holding a color calibration card in the other hand. All images are standardized to enable comparison using a previously established method. First, each image was split into its component 8-bit red, green and blue channels. Each channel’s brightness was adjusted by multiplying its brightness by 200/MB where MB is the mean brightness of the color calibration card’s white square. At this point, the channels were duplicated, with one set merged to produce a 24-bit white-balanced image.

This image standardization technique is not perfect and many times give wrong results. Is there any better image standardization technique available. Any idea or right direction will be helpful.

[image]

**Edit**

As i said above I'm working on the hemoglobin detection from a digital photograph. To reduce the effect of ambient lightning a image standardization technique is to be implemented. Current image standardization technique does not reduce the effect of ambient light to a great extent. The color calibration card in the photograph above could be used for the standardization process. I have heard of "white balance algorithm in mars probe" was used to overcome the same problem but was unable to find a proper source that could give enough information to implement it in `OpenCV`. Another approach or appropriate reference is helpful.

Comment: please provide more details, ideally some code on your white balance approach and especially an example where this gives false results.

Comment: Try with HSV/HSL color space, that might be more helpful in your case.